# Corrupted Images in document directory

Tags: iphone, directory, document

I am fetching URL of the images from the server and converting this images into png format using:
         NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)];
    [data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];

but some of the images are corrupted when i check them after completing the process on simulator.
Hence these images are not displaying on the app wherever needed.

Please see the attached image as some images are corrupted.

[image]

**Update**

I am calling a method in a loop which fetches the images from the server parallel and didFinishLoading I am performing this:
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:self.data];

```
NSArray *split = [self.strImageName componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

int arrCount=[split count];
NSString *imageName=[split objectAtIndex:arrCount-1];



NSString *docDirec = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *pngFilePath=nil
pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Thumbs/%@",docDirec,imageName];


NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)];
[data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];

[self.data release]; //don't need this any more, its in the UIImageView now
self.data=nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the similar problem 
i solved it using the below code

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{



    if  (self.m_objWebManager != nil)//Webmanager is class for downloading the images as a background thread
    {
        [self.m_objWebManager cancelCommunication];

        [self.m_objWebManager release];

        self.m_objWebManager = nil;
    }

}
```